# Build WebRTC for Android application - Video and Audio streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, audio-streaming

I am going through webRTC for Android. I need to develop video and audio chat application. I read many things in webRTC. I am confused where to start with. I did not get proper link.Many said that refer below site.

> https://webrtc.org/reference/getting-started

But I could not find this page itself. Please help me to build webRTC for Android development.

Note: I want opensource code. I don't want any licenced libraries.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/), and you can start by studying [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp/) sample android app.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, Thank you for the reply. I tried with https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/ site.  I installed all the prerequired software and run ninja -C out/Debug. I could not find Debug folder in /src/out/. I have only Default folder. Where I am going wrong?